# Printing Vector on Console

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of type template class and I am trying to print it, but getting a weird error.

Here is my class:

```
template <typename VertexType, typename EdgeType> class Vertex{
private:
    typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, EdgeType> > VertexList;
    std::vector<Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType>> Vertice;

public:
    void Add(Vertex);
};
```

Add Method and Print Statement:

```
template <typename VertexType, typename EdgeType> void Vertex<VertexType, EdgeType> ::Add(Vertex v)
{
    int count = 5;
    //std::vector<string>temp;

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    Vertice.push_back(v);

    for(int i=0; i<Vertice.size(); i++)
        cout<< Vertice[i] <<endl;
}
```

Main() Method:

```
int main()
{
    Vertex<std::string, std::string> v1;

    v1.Add(v1);

    std::getchar();
}
```

Error am getting is:

> error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator
>   found which takes a right-hand operand
>   of type 'Vertex'
>   (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Wrong -> `typedef std::vector<typename> VerticeList;`.... you think `typename` is a type?

Comment: Ohh I am not using that vector as it is anywhere as of now... I will comment that out.

Comment: you didn't comment that.

Comment: I removed it as am not going to use it anywhere

Comment: Isn't this a recursive definition? Vertex is a vector of Vertexes (Vertices?)... Also, don't forget a space between `> >`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't defining an operator << anywhere. You should define it like this out of your class :

```
template <typename VertexType, typename EdgeType>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Vertex<VertexType,EdgeType>& v);
// implementation
template <typename VertexType, typename EdgeType>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Vertex<VertexType,EdgeType>& v) {
    // print whatever you want that represents your vertex

    // please don't forget to return this reference.
    return out;
}
```

Also, having a class with a vector of instances of it inside is a call for trouble. Remember that "vector<Vertice<VertexType,EdgeType> >" is an array of *instances*, not an array of references. If you want a array of 'references' to Vertex, use an array of pointers.

And consider using boost's graph library instead of redefining yet another one and coming to all pitfall associated with graphs (like memory management for instance). The boost library also have some useful algorithms that you could want to use..

Comment: Thanks for including the code sample. Code you note that the prototype can be declared in the class declaration as a static friend? That way, the implementation can actually use all the members of a Vertex

Comment: Most of the operator<< i've written out there doesn't need a friend declaration. Most of the time the public accessors are enough to display valuable information. if it's not, then i find the design a bit dubious: why should i display values that aren't available to the user of the class ?

Comment: Hey BatchyX, I tried your code... I am getting some syntax error: error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '<'

Comment: Did you put the declaration before or after the class declaration ? if before, you need an additional forward declaration, because the compiler doesn't know at that point what a "Vertex" is. but simplest solution is to put the function declaration after the class one.

Comment: Here is my whole code : template <class VertexType, class EdgeType> class Vertex{
protected:
 typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, EdgeType> > VertexList;
 VertexType vertice;
 EdgeType edge;

public:
 Vertex(const VertexType& Value) : vertice(Value) {}
 VertexType Vert() const { return vertice; }
 void Vert(const VertexType& Value) { vertice = Value; }
 void display();

};   template <typename VertexType, typename EdgeType> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Vertice<VertexType,EdgeType>& v);

Comment: Sorry am not aware of how to put the code in code format while putting here in comment section... so it looks like all messed up... :(

Comment: Also, I am working on a assignment and learning... so I cannot use the Boost Library directly as coz I wouldn't be able to learn then

Comment: oops, i overlooked your code. your class is called Vertex, not Vertice. that should be fixed.

Comment: I tried some other way out and the issue is solved now... Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

Well, implement `template <class V, class E> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vertex<V,E> &vertex)` as a static friend of Vertex. It's pretty much what the compiler tells you...